# UPnP deligating play media to 3rd devise

Tags: upnp, dlna

I have a UPnP client and UPnP server, UPnP client discovers the UPnP server and its contents by requesting, now, I want the discovered content to be played in the 3rd device which is initiated by the UPnP client.

Should the 3rd device also discover the UPnP Server? or It can just stream the content from the server based on the URI given by the UPnP Client. (Check the image)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third device (commonly referred to as the Media Renderer) does not need to discover the Media Server.  It relies on the Client (aka Control Point) to select media and just plays whatever url it is passed.

If this doesn't work for you, please update your question to note the services/actions you are using.